# ARC Retain Cycle appears after updating to iOS 6.1

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking, ios6.1

After updating to iOS 6.1, I'm getting this warning in AFImageRequestOperation.m and AFHTTPClient.m from AFNetworking framework:

> Capturing 'operation' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a
>   retain cycle

Based on [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802487/1449151) I can fix a retain cycle in ARC by using __weak variables. It is also says

> Block will be retained by the captured object

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is fixed in AFNetworking 1.1

Comment: Exactly, I downloaded the 1.1.0 and the warnings are disappear. I was downloading the Master branch which didn't have latest commits. Thanks Keith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here was the problem. I was keep downloading the [Master branch](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/archive/master.zip) from GitHub and now that I tried downloading AFNetworking [from here](http://afnetworking.com/) (version 1.1.0) it doesn't show me the warning anymore.

I don't why the latest commits were not included in the master branch when I downloaded but clearly they've solved these strong refs in blocks warnings while ago.

Always check the [website](http://afnetworking.com/) to see the latest released version or sync the latest commit from GitHub :) (It wasn't showing anything in my iOS 6.0 apps but Xcode 4.6 just brought them up)

Answer (score 4):

We are fortunate that XCode 4.6  is showing a warning to avoid this problem
It can be solved by providing  a weak reference

```
AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];

**__weak AFImageRequestOperation *tempRequestOperation = requestOperation;**

[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (success) {
        UIImage *image = responseObject;
        if (imageProcessingBlock) {
            dispatch_async(image_request_operation_processing_queue(), ^(void) {
                UIImage *processedImage = imageProcessingBlock(image);

                dispatch_async(**tempRequestOperation**.successCallbackQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                    success(operation.request, operation.response, processedImage);
                });
            });
        } else {
            success(operation.request, operation.response, image);
        }
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (failure) {
        failure(operation.request, operation.response, error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Hi Sunny, I did the exact same thing but the warnings are still there. I even downloaded the latest AFNetworking framework with all the new commits because I was told that new commits solved these problems while ago but the warnings are still there. Warnings are here:
AFHTTPCliend.m line #564 
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];

and AFImageRequestOperation.m line #85 
dispatch_async(operation.successCallbackQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
success(operation.request, operation.response, processedImage);
}); Btw, my app hasn't crashed or showed any problems.

Comment: I implemented the above solution and it worked for me. So do we have to download the latest version or solution that i provided will work.