# Why the retain cycle warning not thrown?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

I use Xcode 5 and have some code

```
@interface Controller {
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *someView;
}

@implementation Controller {

- (void)doSomething
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        someView.hidden = YES;
    }];
}

- (void)doSomething1
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self doSomething];
    }];
}
```

Why the retain cycle warning not thrown there? Should I use weak references on `self` **every time** I use `self` in blocks?

Also I enabled `Implicit retain of self within blocks` warning and it gave me 100 warnings with advice to write `self->ivar.prop` (not `ivar.prop`) in blocks. Should I do so after that warning is disabled by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the retain cycle warning not thrown there?

The block retains you, but you don't retain the block. It'll be destroyed after animation is complete. So, no cycles.

> Should I use weak references on self every time I use self in blocks?

If your block doesn't get destroyed automatically (e.g. a recurring timer), then you should.

> Should I do so after that warning is disabled by default?

Depends upon the context. Again, if your blocks live for a long time, you might want to declare non-retained `weakSelf`.

But basically you're fine if your blocks don't get saved somewhere.

See also [How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854315/115200)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I missed that block is retained only if it is stored.

Comment: What does it mean for a block to be "long lived"? All blocks have a finite number of lines of code, so it will eventually exit.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a retain cycle. This is two methods calling each other in a loop. A retain cycle happens when two object instances have strong (retained) references to each other that are never broken, and those two objects remain in memory unnecessarily.

Example with code: [Retain cycle in ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802396/retain-cycle-in-arc)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use weak references on self every time I use self in blocks?

Absolutely not. Blocks retain captured object pointers for a reason -- to keep the objects alive until so that they'll still be there when the block is run. If there is no retain cycle and there is no other thing keeping a reference to the object pointed to by `self`, it could be deallocated before the block is run (asynchronously, for example).